# How to use a variable in an array request in php

Tags: php, arrays, variables, while-loop

Im using

```
$i = 0;
while ($i <= 6) {
    print $game['stats']['item0'];
    $i++;
}
```

I want the `item0` to increment to `item1` up to `item6`, so the last while should be
`print $game['stats']['item6'];`

I also tried: `$game['stats']['item{$i}']` but it doesn't work.

Any Ideas for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
while ($i <= 6) {
    $key = 'item'.$i;   
    print $game['stats'][$key];
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: You're welcome, mate. Please vote it up and accept the answer if it solves your purpose. :)

Answer (score 2):

If you need to do something a set number of times, a for loop is generally more concise than a while loop.

```
for ($i=0; $i < 6; $i++) {
    print $game['stats']["item$i"];
}
```

It isn't a more *correct* way of doing it, it really just depends on your style, but I thought it was worth mentioning.

Comment: yeah you are right. I'd never used a for loop. I need to start using it i guess :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should be good to go with this

```
$i = 0;
while ($i <= 6) {
    print $game['stats']["item$i"];
    $i++;
}
```

> When a string is specified in double quotes or with heredoc, variables
>   are parsed within it.

Answer (score 0):

Include the `$i` at the end of the string :

```
<?php
$i = 0;
while ($i <= 6) {
    print $game['stats']['item' . $i];    //<============== , 'item0', 'item1', ...
    $i++;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an edited version of your code. It should work:

```
<?php
$i = 1;
$game = array("stats" => 
array("item1" => 1, "item2" => 2, "item3" => 3, "item4" => 4, "item5" => 5, "item6" => 6 ));
while ($i <= 6) {
    $tmp = 'item'.$i;
    print $game['stats'][$tmp];
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to append $i after item. And you don't need to define new variable.

```
$i = 0;
while ($i <= 6) {
    print $game['stats']['item'.$i];
    $i++;
}
```